# How to integrate WebWorks ePublisher with a Continuous Integration server?

Tags: documentation, continuous-integration

Our documentation is built manually using the [WebWorks ePublisher](http://www.webworks.com/). We would like to have it built automatically on our CI server.

For that there should be a non interactive command line alternative to the ePublisher GUI.

Does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into the WebWorks ePublisher component called [AutoMap](http://www.webworks.com/Documentation/Reverb/#page/01.Welcome%2520to%2520ePublisher/Introduction.4.04.htm#ww1050257).

From [What Is ePublisher AutoMap?](http://www.webworks.com/Documentation/Reverb/index.html#page/03.Preparing%2520and%2520Publishing%2520Content/Automating%2520Projects.5.03.htm#ww1014488):

> ePublisher AutoMap is the automation tool that enables you to automate the content transformation process, batch processing, and integration with content management or version control systems. This component lets you schedule ePublisher projects. For example, you can schedule the output generation to occur overnight. Then, when you arrive the next morning, your transformed content is ready for you. You can also automatically generate and deploy deliverables to meet your specific needs, such as updating Web site content based on updated source documents. You can automatically create ePublisher projects and generate output without manually opening ePublisher or your source documents.

More details here: [Scheduling and Integrating Processes with AutoMap](http://www.webworks.com/Documentation/Reverb/index.html#page/03.Preparing%2520and%2520Publishing%2520Content/Automating%2520Projects.5.01.htm).

Comment: We have ePublisher Pro/Designer Subscription, which means extra $1,995 for the Automap. Is there a cheaper alternative?

Comment: If you want to stay with WebWorks ePublisher, then you'll have to use AutoMap. But if you are prepared to switch to another help authoring tool, then I presume that there are many options.

Comment: Do you have anything to advise? Something to minimize the migration effort?

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice considering that I don't know anything about your current situation or your requirements. I think you should ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, you are right - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181707/are-there-any-free-or-low-cost-alternatives-to-webworks-epublisher